# TinyMCE function causes issue in AVADA theme

Tags: tinymce

I use Avada Theme 5.5.2 + WP and discover an issue that is caused by the function my_tinymce_setup_function( $initArray ). When using this function it updates correct the  into the tables. But in the WP-Admin part I can **not Edit and Save** existing Pages anymore. I ask the Avada Theme guys and they pointed to the function.
I have tried a lot, to correct the function my_tinymce_setup_function(), but I am not well-known with TinyMCE.
So Editing - Saving of  is working fine. Only the function destroys the saving of text at the pages via WP-Admin (back-0ffice).

When testing the code rows from the function I discover that the code in the function is the cause of the issue that appears in AVADA pages. An external coder did code the tinymce parts. But how to change the code correct I have no idea.

I hope that there are members then can help me with this.
Regards

.JS file:

```
window.tinyOnChange = function(ed, l){    
    var orig_element = jQuery(tinyMCE.get(ed.id).getElement());
    var name = orig_element.attr('name');    
    var addid = jQuery( "#pitch_title_up" ).attr('data-pk');    
    var content = ed.getContent();    
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url,'id='+addid+'&name='+name+"&content="+content+'&action=update_text_pitch').done(function(data){
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);   

                /*  if(obj.success){
                        jQuery('.editadvertisement .modal-header button').addClass('close_update_modal');
                        jQuery( '.form-field-text textarea' ).each( function() {
                            if ( jQuery( this ).attr('id') == textarea_id ) {
                                jQuery( this ).next().find("i").show();
                            }
                        });
                    } */
                });
  console.log('Editor contents was modified. Contents: ' + name+ addid);      
}
```

PHP file:

```
function my_tinymce_setup_function( $initArray ) {
$initArray['setup'] = 'function(ed){
    ed.onChange.add(function(ed, l) {
        tinyOnChange(ed,l);
    });
}';
return $initArray;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_tinymce_setup_function' );
```

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Theme-specific questions are considered off-topic here as we help with custom code. Theme authors are more familiar with their own code and can often troubleshoot much more quickly and effectively, especially when you're using a premium theme, where you have paid for support.

Comment: You did not read my thread well. AVADA does not have a clou about tinyMCE. And my question concerns the tinyMCE coding in the function. Nothing else. I can not find solutions on tinymce for the code what is used in that function.

Comment: Sorry, you mentioned Avada so many times it sounded theme-specific. Have you determined where this function is coming from? Child theme, plugin?

Comment: It is from my own plugin. All works great, no debugs no errors. But the function has a bad influence to Avada. Why I dont understand. How to change the code is for me a big question.